# How can I use a custom/dynamic attribute for a view in Ember JS?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

My Handlebars file looks a bit like this:

```
{{#each book in view.bookcase}}
  {{view App.BookView classBinding="book.read:read:unread"}}
{{/each}}
```

I'd like to add an attribute to the tune of `book-id="1"` or whatever the current book's ID is, but I have no idea how. If I try this...

```
{{#each book in view.bookcase}}
  {{view App.BookView book-id="book.id" classBinding="book.read:read:unread"}}
{{/each}}
```

...then the attribute literally gets set to "book.id". Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, at first I thought using `attributeBindings` was allowed according to [this post](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/260#issuecomment-3158823) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396017/bind-custom-attributes-on-ember-view-with-controller-data-in-xhandlebars-script), but when I try to do it, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Setting 'attributeBindings' via Handlebars is not allowed. Please subclass Ember.View and set it there instead.
```

So I think the best method now is by doing it in the class instead.

Handlebar template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each book in view.bookcase}}
        {{view App.BookView classBinding="book.read:read:unread" contentBinding="book"}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Extended class:

```
App.BookView = Ember.View.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['book-id'],
    'book-id': function() {
        return this.content.id;
    }.property('content.id')
});
```

Example: [jsFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/6T3Sp/1/)